# What does the chart tell me?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, probability-distributions

I just created this chart from a data source and I'm trying to figure out what it can tell me, just by looking at it. I know it's a mess, but there are some key things I'm able to pull out:

- absolute min is more than -40
- absolute max is about 118
- the majority is positive (or the positives are more "extreme"?)
- something "magical" seems to happen in hour 15 for negative lines, they go up 0-20
- 80%+ (visual) of data is above -20

The things I will further investigate is:

- 1/2/3 standard deviation, maybe it will help if I can use that as a filter

The goal here is to be able to say that with % of certainty that min value will not be below x (min) and under y (max). Or do I treat it as two separate facts (not x AND y)? Do I run standard deviation and call it a day, whats within 68%? Say 1 negative standard deviation is -18, and one standard deviation for all positive numbers is +27 for instance? That's a "actionable" absolute difference of 9. Should I use averages instead of standard deviation? What is the advantages of standard deviation and averages?

What do you see when you see this chart? What would you do in order to investigate the data? Sorry, I don't have a mathematical background, yet I've collected data I want to understand. I've tried to get the image inline, but it's represented as a link, sorry again.

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y09Gd.png)

I've added the average and standard deviation calculations. I'm a bit surprised that the skew ins't larger. By looking at the graph I would guess that standard deviation for H15 for instance would be higher for the positive numbers then for the negative, which is not (14.07 vs 19.81). This tells me that the positive numbers are more extreme, but bulk of the data is negative for H15? What else can I do with this?

First on the whole dataset, and then on the positive numbers and negative numbers:

```
    Calulcating on the whole dataset:
         0, average:  0,00, stdv:  0,00
         1, average: -0,20, stdv:  4,73
         2, average:  0,63, stdv:  6,17
         3, average:  0,88, stdv:  7,22
         4, average:  0,63, stdv:  7,90
         5, average:  0,03, stdv:  8,06
         6, average:  0,46, stdv:  8,47
         7, average:  0,36, stdv:  9,68
         8, average:  0,65, stdv:  13,62
         9, average: -0,01, stdv:  15,77
        10, average:  0,06, stdv:  17,16
        11, average: -0,11, stdv:  18,00
        12, average: -1,03, stdv:  20,11
        13, average: -0,43, stdv:  21,73
        14, average:  0,56, stdv:  23,25
        15, average:  0,01, stdv:  26,35
        16, average: -0,49, stdv:  28,78
        17, average: -0,49, stdv:  31,24
        18, average: -0,65, stdv:  31,93
        19, average: -0,75, stdv:  34,49
        20, average: -0,70, stdv:  33,94
        21, average: -1,29, stdv:  33,32
        22, average: -1,71, stdv:  28,65
        23, average:  0,95, stdv:  26,75

Calulcating on positive numbers in dataset:
         H1, average:  4,62, stdv:  4,35
         H2, average:  5,83, stdv:  4,94
         H3, average:  6,80, stdv:  5,83
         H4, average:  7,02, stdv:  6,24
         H5, average:  6,89, stdv:  6,24
         H6, average:  7,14, stdv:  6,32
         H7, average:  7,89, stdv:  6,63
         H8, average:  11,04, stdv:  8,42
         H9, average:  11,00, stdv:  10,21
        H10, average:  12,97, stdv:  11,75
        H11, average:  12,35, stdv:  11,85
        H12, average:  15,00, stdv:  13,82
        H13, average:  16,94, stdv:  14,53
        H14, average:  18,27, stdv:  13,74
        H15, average:  18,63, stdv:  14,07
        H16, average:  21,05, stdv:  15,91
        H17, average:  21,47, stdv:  18,13
        H18, average:  23,20, stdv:  18,65
        H19, average:  24,23, stdv:  21,28
        H20, average:  26,28, stdv:  19,60
        H21, average:  24,92, stdv:  19,56
        H22, average:  23,89, stdv:  20,93
        H23, average:  24,23, stdv:  22,18

Calulcating on negative numbers in dataset:
         H1: average: -3,68, stdv:  2,14
         H2: average: -4,38, stdv:  3,31
         H3: average: -5,22, stdv:  3,94
         H4: average: -5,80, stdv:  4,45
         H5: average: -6,06, stdv:  4,60
         H6: average: -6,61, stdv:  5,61
         H7: average: -8,17, stdv:  5,24
         H8: average: -11,29, stdv:  9,43
         H9: average: -13,38, stdv:  12,14
        H10: average: -13,60, stdv:  11,27
        H11: average: -15,21, stdv:  11,59
        H12: average: -16,06, stdv:  13,52
        H13: average: -16,64, stdv:  14,48
        H14: average: -18,96, stdv:  15,78
        H15: average: -22,98, stdv:  19,81
        H16: average: -25,02, stdv:  20,63
        H17: average: -28,52, stdv:  22,21
        H18: average: -26,65, stdv:  22,98
        H19: average: -29,49, stdv:  23,31
        H20: average: -28,10, stdv:  22,42
        H21: average: -27,93, stdv:  22,39
        H22: average: -26,16, stdv:  22,01
        H23: average: -24,91, stdv:  21,86
```

Comment: It might help if you tell us the source of the data, as that will suggest questions and information to extract.  Is this a *single* situation, repeated many times?  The horizontal axis represent *time*... but what about the vertical?

Comment: Hi @DavidG.Stork ! Thank you for your reply. Each line is a occurrence of the same action, where its result is the line that is plotted. So hour "3" means 3rd hour from start and the value is the result that hour. It continues thru the day and each hour results then makes a line that is plotted.